# Regular expression for specific condtions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble checking with RegEx trying to match the following:

- letters : upper or lowercase
- numbers : 0-9
- some special characters : @#$&)(*^'!_-
- single whitespace between characters
- not empty or whitespace only
- no leading or trailing whitespaces

A few examples:

- OK: "abc"
- OK: "ABC"
- OK: "123"
- OK: "@#$"
- OK: "acbABC123@#$"
- OK: "abc ABC 123 @#$"
- NOT OK: ""
- NOT OK: " "
- NOT OK: "abcABC~%+123@#$"
- NOT OK: " abc ABC 123 @#$ "

What would be the correct RegEx to accommodate all these conditions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the enclosing "quote" marks are not actually included in your strings. Is this what you want?

`^[A-Za-z0-9@#$&)(*^'!_-]+(?: [A-Za-z0-9@#$&)(*^'!_-]+)*$`

Basically, it is saying "Any of the characters that you allow at the beginning, followed by one or more optional blocks of those characters preceded by a single space." This allows for a single whitespace between "words", and must start and end with a non-whitespace character.

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/qL6DnF/1)